# MySQL - CHECK constraint connecting two tables

Tags: mysql, constraints

At the moment I'm trying my hands in MySql DataBase. I already created few tables with game players info.
Right now i created table with account data. I'd like to create check constraint in that table that compares date value from "account" table with "users" table.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id BIGINT(20) unique auto_increment,
first_name VARCHAR(45), 
last_name VARCHAR (45),
birth date not null,
gender enum ('M', 'F'),
PRIMARY KEY (id) );

CREATE TABLE account (
account_id BIGINT(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
account_type ENUM('STANDARD','GOLD','PLATINUM','DIAMOND','LEGENDARY'),
discount INT (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK(discount<16),
create_date date NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES users(id));
```

I want to be unable to add account create_date that is smaller than users birth (date). I already checked fucntions and triggers, but I'm newbie to this , and I would like to know if anyone had this problem and if it is possible. I don't know how to create functions or triggers. If you know any sources with step by step explanation I'll be grateful.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: CHECK constraint may check field values in current record only. Another records or records in another tables cannot be checked. Use trigger logic.

Comment: ' If you know any sources with step by step explanation I'll be grateful.' - manual is good https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html but looads of searchable stuff out there

Comment: Perhaps you should be validating birth date and allow create date to be automatically entered rather than keyed.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: As an alternative, you could build the logic into the query itself.

Comment: Use trigger logic. `INSTEAD OFF` triggers normally does the trick. See what is MYSQL's flavour of the `INSTEAD OFF` trigger

Comment: I'm using 8.0 version. I'll look into triggers then. But i also found mistake in my logic. I'm creating accounts after user "creation" , so it is not possible to create account before it's user birth.  But the feature i seek may be useful when the birth date is edited after account creation.  I'll look into manual. Thank you all for help.